# Probability an binomial experiment terminates

Tags: probability, distributions, coupon-collector-problem

I was recently thinking of how to calculate that an experiment terminates after a given amount of turns.

An example would be something similar to opening packs of baseball cards.

Suppose there are a total of 100 packs of baseball cards, and randomly placed in 10 of these packs is a rare card. How would you calculate, say, how many packs of cards would you need to open until you have a 50% chance of getting a rare card?

Initially I thought using the hypergeometric distribution makes sense, but in a sense you have to initially pick an amount of draws. (i.e. I buy 30 packs of cards and open all of them). In this case the calculation is rather simple by calculating the chance of getting atleast 1 card.

But what if I didn't want to initially draw $n$ draws, and I only wanted 1 card?

(I keep on conducting the experiment until I get one success (rare card)).

Like buy a pack, check if it has rare card,

if yes, stop

if no, buy another pack.

(This is a bit later) I just tried the cumulative negative hypergeometric distribution (how many packs opened until a 50% probability you have opened one) and it gave the same result as the calculation for the hypergeometric distribution so now I'm even more confused.

Comment: this is a coupon-collector problem, search this site.

Comment: I see how this may be related but aren't coupon collector problems under the assumption that each "draw" has the same probability of obtaining a particular unit? In my case every unsuccessful draw increases the probability that the next draw will have a success.